# Array Indexing Issue

Tags: c++

I think i have an array indexing problem with the following code It compiles o.k. in Orwell Dev CPP but when i run it i get up and down arrows for output which i think indicates some sort of problem with one of the condition statements. I was expecting all numeric output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std ;

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   char name[2] ;

   cout << "Type aa ab ba or bb" << endl ;

   fgets(name , 2, stdin) ;

   cout << "The first letter of the name is " << name[0] << endl ;
   cout << "The second letter of the name is " << name[1] << endl ;

   int name_length ;

   name_length = strlen(name) -1 ;

   cout << "The length of the name is " << name_length << endl;

   char Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[2][2] ;

   /* Set the Main Chaldean Kaballah */

   Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[1][1] = 'A' ;
   Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[2][1] = 'B' ;

   Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[1][2] = 1 ;
   Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[2][2] = 2 ;

   unsigned int x = 0 ;
   unsigned int Chaldean_Letter_Index ;

   cout << "Name_Lenght is " << name_length  << "Chaldean_Letter_Index "<< Chaldean_Letter_Index << "x " << x << endl ;

   for ( x = 0 ; name_length  >= x; x = x + 1 ) {

      cout << "x " << x << "Name Length is " << name_length << endl ;

      for (Chaldean_Letter_Index = 1; Chaldean_Letter_Index <= 2 ; Chaldean_Letter_Index = Chaldean_Letter_Index+ 1) {

         cout << "Chaldean Letter Index" << Chaldean_Letter_Index << endl ;

         cout << "x " << x  <<"Name letter " << name[x] << endl ;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

arr[2][2] array will have

```
arr[0][0] arr[0][1]
arr[1][0] arr[1][1]
```

The below are out of index range

```
Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[2][1] = 'B' ;
 Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[1][2] = 1 ;
 Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[2][2] = 2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing most of your array indexing wrong.  Your subscripts in `Kaballah_Chaldean_Main` are 1-based, but C++ uses 0-based arrays.  You should use `Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[0][0]` etc to avoid going outside the bounds of the array.

Also the `Chaldean_Letter_Index` should start at 0 and end at 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

```
fgets(name , 2, stdin);
```

reads at most one character to `name`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets for more details.

If you want to read 2 characters, use:

```
char name[3] ;

cout << "Type aa ab ba or bb" << endl ;

fgets(name , 3, stdin) ;
```

**Problem 2**

```
name_length = strlen(name) -1 ;
```

It makes more sense for it to be:

```
name_length = strlen(name);
```

**Problem 3**

You have:

```
char Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[2][2] ;

/* Set the Main Chaldean Kaballah */

Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[1][1] = 'A' ; 
Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[2][1] = 'B' ;

Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[1][2] = 1 ;
Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[2][2] = 2 ;
```

Those are wrong indices. You are modifying memory beyond the valid limits. The valid range of indices for `Kaballah_Chaldean_Main` is `[0][0]` - `[1][1]`. Those lines should be:

```
Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[0][0] = 'A' ; 
Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[1][0] = 'B' ;

Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[0][1] = 1 ;
Kaballah_Chaldean_Main[1][1] = 2 ;
```

**Problem 4**

You have the following variable:

```
unsigned int Chaldean_Letter_Index ;
```

It is not initialized before it's used in the next line. Perhaps it should be initialized to 0.

```
unsigned int Chaldean_Letter_Index = 0;
```